# Get the values of input fields within child elements of a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have my form broken up into sections, and I'm trying to have a script check the number of fields empty in each section. Previously I had written an array with the id's of each section and had it cycle through that array, but i'd like to find a more universal solution that doesn't depend on predefined data.

at first I was trying .find() like so

```
function blankFields(section){
    var totblank = 0;
    var inputs = $('#' + section).find('input');
    $.each(inputs, function(){
        if(this.val() == '') { totblank++; );
    }
```

when that didn't work i tried .serializeArray()

```
function blankFields(section){
    var totblank = 0;
    var inputs = $('#' + section + ' input').serializeArray();
    $.each(inputs, function(i, field) {
        if (field.value == '') { totblank++; }
    });
```

and it gets followed up with

```
    if(totblank > 0){
        $("#"+section+"B").html(totblank+" Empty");
    } else {
        $("#"+section+"B").html("All full!");
    }       
}
```

section is the id of a div, the div has a table with form inputs.

This is my first time using these functions so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. Feels like I'm expecting the output to be something its not.

Comment: Is "+= totblank" valid syntax?

Comment: @Tx3, Just going to ask the same thing. I've never seen that before and doesn't seem, at first glance, to be valid. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: oops, you're right it should be totblank++. I also forgot to set it. updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors in your code. Fixed:

```
function blankFields(section){
   var totblank = 0;
   var inputs = $('#' + section).find('input');
   inputs.each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == '') totblank++;
   });

   alert(totblank); 
}
```

Comment: I knew I was just botching the syntax. This worked, but I had to create a second one that did the same thing for select boxes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to find all empty fields, and browse back the DOM to retrieve the parent section.

After, store results in associative array like `"section" => count`. If the section isn't in array, add an entry `"newsection" => 1`, else if section is in, increment section's count.

Answer (score 0):

I think this part should give you an error

```
+= totblank
```

Or maybe I don't know JavaScript syntax well enough..

Anyway, try this instead

```
totblank++;
```

Overall, it's also good to make sure you're really dealing with Numbers. Common mistake is to get `.val()` and do some maths for example `'1' + 1`. Result is 11 and is something you probably didn't want

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a little snippet that does the trick : http://jsfiddle.net/9jdmH/

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    $('.section').each(function() {
        checkSection($(this));
    });
})

function checkSection(section) {
    //assuming we're getting a jquery object. easily modifieable
    section.find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#log').prepend('<p>Found an empty input section ' + section.index() + '</p>');
        }
    })
}
```

This will work for a general markup type.

You'll need to make some changes depending on what kind of information you want. I haven't used IDs so I'm just using the `.index()` point out which ones are empty. As long as you get/make a jquery reference in the `checkSection` method you'll be fine.

Comment: the filter I applied (`input[type="text"]`) checks for textboxes. You can remove the filter to make it work for checkboxes too.

Comment: if you add a .filter("[value='']") you can remove the .val() == '' check

Comment: @potatopeelings yup, but not sure how it would behave around checkboxes where checked attribute is what is needed

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:
http://jsfiddle.net/fqBrS/

```
function findNumberOfEmptyInputs(section) {
    var inputs = $('#'+section+' input[type="text"]');
    alert(inputs.filter(":empty").length);

}
findNumberOfEmptyInputs("section2");
```

The good thing is that you do not have to (explictly at least) use a loop.
Comments appreciated :)

Comment: OP wants to move to a solution where he doesn't have to pass the list of sections to the function.

Comment: the initial post, although stating that, seems to suggest otherwise, also see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

code with sample. Should give pretty much the same output you have now.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkBlank(f){
            $(f).find(".section").each(function () {
                var c = $(this).find("input[value='']").size()
                $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "B").text(c ? c + " Empty" : "All full");
            })
            return false
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit="return checkBlank(this)">
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section2">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Click">
    </form>

    <div id="section1B"></div>
    <div id="section2B"></div>
</body>
</html>
```